# make trigger to avoid conflict

Tags: mysql

I have booking table

```
id     room     date_IN         date_OUT
 1      101      29-12-2016      1-1-2017
 2      102      29-12-2016      2-1-2017
 3      101      1-1-2017        4-1-2017
```

how can I make trigger to avoid conflict date if I modify date_OUT of (id=1) to 3-1-2017

Comment: Why would that be a duplicate?

Comment: How will doing what you say create duplicate?

Comment: I mean conflict

Comment: what makes it a conflict?

Comment: becuse room 101 is booking from 1-1-2017 to 4-1-2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Trigger: Prevent Insert by IF statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691236/mysql-trigger-prevent-insert-by-if-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create 2 triggers `BEFORE UPDATE` and `BEFORE INSERT`. Then check if the new date you want to insert or update is between date_IN and date_OUT of another entry.

An example would be

```
CREATE TABLE booking (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   room INT,
   date_IN date,
   date_OUT date
);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `booking_duplicate_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `booking`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF EXISTS (SELECT date_IN, date_OUT FROM booking WHERE date_IN <= NEW.date_IN AND date_OUT > NEW.date_OUT) THEN 
 SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
 SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
 END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `booking_duplicate_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `booking`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF EXISTS (SELECT date_IN, date_OUT FROM booking WHERE date_IN <= NEW.date_IN AND date_OUT > NEW.date_OUT) THEN 
 SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
 SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
 END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

insert into booking (room, date_IN, date_OUT) VALUES (101, '2016-12-29', '2017-01-01');
insert into booking (room, date_IN, date_OUT) VALUES (101, '2017-01-01', '2017-01-04');

// Should fail to insert
insert into booking (room, date_IN, date_OUT) VALUES (101, '2017-01-02', '2017-01-02');
```